# Printing out arrays in certain way

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, output

So i have 3 different arrays, one name[], one age[] and one phonenumber[]

I then want to print all the information stored in these out ex.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++ ){
 name[i]
 age[i]
 phonenumber[i]
}
```

But how do I have to write in the for loop for the output to say it in this format?:

```
Person 1: name[i] age[i] phonenumber[i]
Person 2: name[i+1] age[i+1] phonenumber [i+1]
(Example) Person 3: Jake 14 0704156671
```

and so on.

Comment: Java? Or is it a similar language?

Comment: Yeah its java, sorry forgot to mention

Answer (score 1):

You're not telling anything to print the values out. Java uses `System.out` to print stuff to the console.

Thus, simply writing `name[i]` doesn't really do anything. It just points at the value in the array, and moves on.

Instead, fill the for-loop with

```
System.out.println("Person " + (i+1) + ": " + name[i] + " " + age[i] + " " + phonenumber[i]);
```

In the future, you're likely going to be learning about Object Oriented Programming. As of right now, it's very likely that at some point `name[5]` will have the name of a different person than the one whose age you're referencing with `age[5]`. If any of the arrays are changed in any way, all the data will be wrong.

A common way to deal with this is to store the attributes onto, for example, a `Person` object, which holds data for each individual item.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<name.length; i++){
    System.out.println("Person " +(i+1) + ": " +name[i] + " " +age[i] + " " +phonenumber[i]);
}
```